# Linkage between php and java

Tags: java, php

I have a PHP script and I want to sell it to other programmers. To prevent them from redistributing it I want to protect it with a license key.

I want to put on license key in this script ,but there is any problem with coding. This problem is - if i use any license key on this script i must do if-else in this coding, but any PHP programmer can read it, and he can use this script without a license after modify this script. Is any way to linkage between php and java for use php code as java class and compile all this script as application?

Comment: When it would be possible, what would it solve? It would be possible to decompile the Java class and extract your license key. You could use an obfuscator on the Java class, but that would only make it more complicated, not impossible.

Comment: i want to sell this php script wiht license key, but there  are more programmer after buying script they will modify script for himself,and they will sell script too.is there any way to encode script and nobody can use this without a license?

Comment: so YOU want to generate a license key system for YOUR software, no licensed 3rd party software is involved? Also, what do you want to prevent: Redistribution or modification?

Comment: @Aliyev_Z This has been asked a million times. If you don't want them to steal your sourcecode, then sell it as a service. Obfuscating, merging it with java and any other techniques will just hinder you and hinder the client. If you still insist, there is [ioncube](http://www.ionCube.com), but the client would need to install a PHP extension which is not possible unless they have a VPS/dedicated server.

Comment: HamZa, ioncube is not reliable too thats way after 2-3 month is publishing a new version of ioncube, and to old version is aviabling many decoders:) Are you know merging java with php? If is there any way i want be to go with thats way:) on java its very easy to do, thats way want to merging php with java.